# Renaming using capture groups in Bash

Tags: regex, bash

I would like to rename several files of the format

```
libabc-x86_64-gnu-linux.a
libasdfgh-x86-gnu-linux.a
```

all to the format

```
libabc.a
libasdfgh.a
```

using Bash.  I have written the regex `(libpj[^-]*).*`, which should leave the interesting part in capture group 1.  So I tried to use parameter substitution with Bash:

```
for i in `ls *.a`; do mv "$i" "${i/(lib[^-]*).*/\1}"; done
```

But Bash gives many errors of the form

```
mv: 'libabc-x86_64-gnu-linux.a' and 'libabc-x86_64-gnu-linux.a' are the same file
```

implying that the regex is somehow not matching, even though I have confirmed that it does with several utilities, especially the very excellent [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/).  What am I doing wrong?  Does Bash have trouble with capture groups?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
for i in *.a; do
   mv "$i" "${i%%-*}.a"
done
```

`%%` will remove a matching suffix pattern; in this case, it removes `-*`, or everything starting with the first `-`.

Comment: This is covered under `Parameter Expansion` section in `man bash`

Comment: See [it online here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: Much cleaner than mine.  I have long since concluded that Bash has infinite features, and the Bash man page is in fact the Book of Sand.  Thanks!